# Do not understand how to return an answer to a function array within an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a new array object in my `Promise` function and I'm also trying to add user parameters from the  `getUser` function.

I'm struggling to get the data into the array.

Could someone give me an example of how I could implement this?

Thanks.

```
      var results_array = [];
    return callHistory(76).then((result)=>{
        _.map(result, (item, index) => {
            var obj = JSON.parse(item.params);
            results_array[index] = {
                 id: item.id,
                 status: item.status,
                 timestamp: item.timestamp,
                 from_id:obj.from_id,
                 to_id: obj.to_id,
                 conference: obj.conference,
                 to:"",
                 from:getUser(10)

            };
        });


        res.json({
            status: 1,
            result: results_array
        })
        //return results_array;
    })

function getUser(id){

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            connection.query(`SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ${id} `, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                return resolve(results);
            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: I dont get the benefit of using lodash on nodejs...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Where are you using `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first lets beautify getUser a bit:

```
function getUser(id){
  return connection.query(`SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ${id} `);
}
```

Async await can also be used in loops making your main loop more elegant too:

```
async function getHistory(index){
  const history = await callHistory(index), result = [];

  for(const call of history){
    const params = JSON.parse( call.params );
    params.to = "";
    params.from = await getUser( 10 /*params.from*/ );

    result.push( params );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Usable as:

```
getHistory(76)
  .then( result => res.json({status:1, result })
  .catch( error => res.json({status:500, error });
```

Comment: "*At first lets beautify getUser a bit*" - no, [you cannot replace the `new Promise` constructor with `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572). `connection.query` takes a callback.

Comment: @bergi maybe. E.g. the mongodb driver returns a promise if no callback was passed. That depends on the implementation ( and it looks like it *works* for the OP)

Comment: Ah ok. Still, in that case you shouldn't use `async`/`await` either, just write ``function getUser(id){ return connection.query(`SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ${id} `); }``