# Refactoring promise function to es6 format, await doesn't actually await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

So I'm just revisiting some old code to tidy up and modernize some syntax in my [Partum-React](https://github.com/LucHighwalker/partum-react) project. But when I reformat this specific older traditional `function() return new Promise...` to an `async () => ...return...` type function, it doesn't seem to await for the function to be finished. The answers I found don't seem to solve my problem, since as far as I can tell, my async function is written correctly and should work as expected. I also already reformatted some older function/promise functions into async functions without an issue. So I'm pretty stumped on why this specific function doesn't seem to get properly wrapped in a promise.

The old function which works as expected, program properly awaits for the function to complete before continuing execution (found in `helper.js` in the `/src` folder):

```
function shell(command, log = false, cb = null) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(stdout);
        if (log) process.stdout.write(`\n${stdout}\n\n`);
        resolve({
          stdout,
          stderr,
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Rewritten function, doesn't seem to properly await when called with await. consecutive `shell` calls are run synchronously causing git to error out. I'm sure it's a small mistake on my part, but I just can't seem to see it. As far as I know, this function should be properly wrapped in a promise and function as such:

```
const shell = async (command, log = false, cb = null) => {
  exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (cb) cb(stdout);
    if (log) process.stdout.write(`\n${stdout}\n\n`);
    return {
      stdout,
      stderr,
    };
  });
};
```

This is where the function is being called (found in `initializer.js` in the `/src` folder) (I know, this also needs some major cleaning up):

```
finalize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      process.stdout.write('finalizing project\n');
      copy(this.tempPath, this.destination, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          process.stdout.write('cleaning up temporary files\n');
          rmdir(this.tempPath, async (err) => { // eslint-disable-line
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              try {
                await shell(`mkdir ${path.join(this.destination, this.options.componentPath)}`);

                if (this.options.redux) {
                  await shell(`mkdir ${path.join(this.destination, this.options.reduxPath, this.options.actionPath)}`);
                }

                await shell(`git -C ${this.destination} init`);
                await shell(`git -C ${this.destination} add .`);
                await shell(`git -C ${this.destination} commit -m 'Initialized with Partum-React'`);

                process.stdout.write(
                  `\nrunning npm install inside ${this.destination}\n`,
                );
                await npmInstall(this.destination, this.silent);

                resolve(true);

              } catch (err) { // eslint-disable-line
                reject(err);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

console logging `shell(....)` without await logs `Promise {undefined}`

console logging `await shell(....)` with await logs `{undefined}`

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

Comment: No, the rewritten function won't be properly awaited as it does not return a promise. The 'old' function is a correct version if you want to use it with `async/await` syntax.

Comment: The rewritten `shell` function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: If in the old syntax you had to use `new Promise`, then moving to the newer syntax does not mean you can drop that part. Also, an `async` function without the `await` keyword is most often a sign that something is wrong. In your case there is no good reason to convert your function to the `async` syntax. The latter is more interesting for when you have a chain of `then` calls.

Comment: I was under the impression that an async function will always return a value as a promise without needing to explicitly construct a new promise return value. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your `async` function is not written correctly. You [cannot replace the `new Promise` constructor by `async`/`await` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572). If something provides only a callback API, you need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) it before being able to use `await` on it.

You should be doing

```
function shell(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve({stdout, stderr});
      }
    });
  });
}
function copy(source, destination) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    …
  });
}
function rmdir(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    …
  });
}
```

and then you can write your `finalise` function using `async`/`await`:

```
async finalize() {
  process.stdout.write('finalizing project\n');
  await copy(this.tempPath, this.destination);
  process.stdout.write('cleaning up temporary files\n');
  await rmdir(this.tempPath);
  await shell(`mkdir ${path.join(this.destination, this.options.componentPath)}`);
  if (this.options.redux) {
    await shell(`mkdir ${path.join(this.destination, this.options.reduxPath, this.options.actionPath)}`);
  }
  await shell(`git -C ${this.destination} init`);
  await shell(`git -C ${this.destination} add .`);
  await shell(`git -C ${this.destination} commit -m 'Initialized with Partum-React'`);
  process.stdout.write(`\nrunning npm install inside ${this.destination}\n`);
  await npmInstall(this.destination, this.silent);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const shell = async (command, log = false, cb = null) => {
  /*problem lies here, because most probably this is a async function and 
  therefore undefined is returned from this function as resolved value*/

  exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (cb) cb(stdout);
    if (log) process.stdout.write(`\n${stdout}\n\n`);
    return {
      stdout,
      stderr,
    };
  });
};
```

[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703692/using-try-catch-on-error-generated-by-asynchronous-callback-function?noredirect=1#comment101854283_57703692)