# Convert child process based Promise to async await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, child-process, spawn

This is my existing code. I tried to get data with a child process spawned, and the promise resolves after the child is terminated

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

const getDataFromChildProcess = params => new Promise(resolve => {
  const child = spawn('script.js',[params])
  let data = null
  child.on('data',result => {
    data = result
  })
  child.on('exit',() => {
    resolve(data)
  })
})


getDataFromChildProcess('foo')
.then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

How do I convert it into async-await style?

Comment: You [cannot convert `getDataFromChildProcess` to `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572), only the `.then()` call.

Comment: I see, so my suspicion was true

Answer (score 0):

`await` will work inside `async` function. For your example - you will need to wrap your operation inside a `async fn`.

With that said you When you wrap something with a `fn`, you will need to execute that `fn` too. For that I used IIFE in my example- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

const getDataFromChildProcess = params => new Promise(resolve => {
  const child = spawn('script.js',[params])
  let data = null
  child.on('data',result => {
    data = result
  })
  child.on('exit',() => {
    resolve(data)
  })
})


(async() => {
 try{
    const result = await getDataFromChildProcess('foo')
    console.log(result)
  } catch(e) {
     console.log(e)
   }
})()
```

Comment: You're missing the point, what I want to convert is the getDataFromChildProcess function, not how to execute that