# Can I return a resolved promise using just async in JS?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, callback, es6-promise

I saw that putting `async` in front of a JS function returns a Promise.

What I have now:

```
    async function asyncTest(p) {
        return p;
    } 

    let www = asyncTest(1)
    console.log('www ', www); // returns Promise {<fulfilled>: 1}, see image
```

[image]

I was wondering if I could use this to have resolved and rejected in an `async`, acting like a typical `new Promise((resolved, rejected)....`

What I would like to do:

```
    async function asyncTest(p, (resolved, rejected)=>{

      resolved(p);

    }) 

    let www = asyncTest(1)
    console.log('www ', www); // I want it to return 1
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: `async` functions _always_ return promises (as does `new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...)`), you can't somehow re-synchronise it to get the value without either `await` or `.then`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. First you acknowledge that an `async` function always returns a promise object, but then you want `www` *not* to be a promise object??

Comment: If you don't want to return a promise, write an ordinary function that creates a promise and calls `resolve()` itself.

Comment: If you want to generate an *asynchronous* result, then that result will be available in the *future*, and you cannot expect it to be available *now*.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I could use this to have resolved and rejected in an `async`, acting like a typical `new Promise((resolved, rejected)…`

No. An `async` function does not provide you with callbacks to resolve/reject a promise, it only provides you with `await`. You can re-create `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` with

```
async function resolve(x) { return x; }
async function reject(x) { throw x; }`
```

but that's it. To [promisify a callback API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572), you [always need to use the `new Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788934/1048572).